# Wanting to provide a UITextField and Slide up a TaskDetailListView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

In my tableViewCell, when the UILabel is tapped, the label becomes an inplace UITextField editor with a keyboard sliding Up from the bottom. Along with that, scroll up a detailsListView up to the bottom of the NodeCell with more details about the "NodeCell" that I can edit.

The way I have heard of how to implement this is scroll up of detailsViewController is via performSegueWithIdentifier. Maybe so but I need the tapped UITableViewcell animated to the top
with inplace editing as well as see the detailsViewController at the same time. Examples I have seen online is where the destinationViewController 
slides on filling the window while the taskListView disappears.

So I have some questions:

1) How would I get the UILabel converted into a UITextField upon Tap? I mean like do I have to have two subviews (1 UITextField and 1 UILabel). Can I do it with just one subView. 
Is there a way where I can make the UITextField appear like a UILabel or would I need to implement my own custom UITextField?

My possible solution so far:
I was thinking that I create a UIViewController, with a UITableView
The tapped UITableViewCell will cause the UITableView frame to move up to the cells or up to the top along using UIView block animation, fade out the cells that weren't click and slide up a UIView up to designated location. To me, this means everything can be done in the one UIViewController without the need for two view controllers.

What you reckon?

Not too sure if I wrote this code the right way. Will have to go through the docs again possibly.

Here is my implementation for fading the UITableViewCells below the tappedCell. It works.

```
CGRect originalLocation;
CGRect newLocation;
NSInteger cellRow;
cellRow = indexPath.row;

  //Retrieve all the cells below the current tapped cell excluding the current tapped cell and push them into an array  
    NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < 1; ++j)
    {
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:j]; ++i)
        {
            if (i != cellRow && i > cellRow){
            [cells addObject:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]]];
            }
        }
    }

    //Change the alpha of the cells below tappedCell
    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < cells.count; ++j) {
        cell = [cells objectAtIndex:j];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.1
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{

                             cell.contentView.alpha = 0.05;
                             cell.backgroundView.alpha = 0.05;

                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Done!");


                         }];

    }


//get UITableView newLocation from tableView Frame minus the tappedCell origin.   
originalLocation = [self.tableView frame];//[self.tabview frame];
newLocation = originalLocation;
newLocation.origin.y = originalLocation.origin.y - rect.origin.y - 25; //I think the cell height is 25. 

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.1
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     [self.tableView setFrame:newLocation];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");


                 }];
```

This code is only for the fade and the slide up of the tasklist. Doesn't include the detailsList. Not sure if I implemented this right. 
Like to hear your opinions on this one.

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: do u have any screenshot of what you are willing to achieve?

Comment: A UITextField can be non editable by setting the `.editable property` to NO. Have you considered using just a UITextField?